# Importing CSV file with Japanese Characters to Excel using pywin32

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings

Hello guys I had this problem in which I can't seem to open **CSV** file with Japanese character in Excel

it shows random character glyphs, or '?????' how can I export **CSV** file into **Excel** and remove display issues

Answer (score 0):

By using **pywin32** and **xlwings** library you can access the **Excel VBA QueryTables**  here is how I did it

```
import xlwings.constants
import win32com.client

def csv_to_xlsx(self, csv_file):
    try:
        csv_file = str(csv_file.replace('/','\\'))
        excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        excel.DisplayAlerts = False
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()

        scsht = workbook.Worksheets[1]
        qtnew = scsht.QueryTables.Add(
            Connection= "TEXT;{}".format(csv_file),
            Destination = scsht.Range("A1"))
        qtnew.TextFilePlatform = 65001
        qtnew.TextFileStartRow = 1
        qtnew.TextFileParseType = xlwings.constants.TextParsingType.xlDelimited
        qtnew.TextFileTextQualifier = xlwings.constants.TextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        qtnew.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        qtnew.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        qtnew.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        qtnew.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        qtnew.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        qtnew.TextFileColumnDataTypes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        qtnew.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        qtnew.Refresh()
        workbook.SaveAs(csv_file.replace('.csv', '.xlsx'))
        workbook.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        os.remove(csv_file)
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
```

now the **CSV** file is exported to **Excel** and the characters can be viewed properly.